# Is it possible to create new xml elements with XPath using MSXML DOM? How?

Tags: xml, xpath, msxml

Is it possible to create new xml elements with XPath(or another kind of path) using MSXML DOM? (function names are imaginary but understandable)

Something like:

```
node n = document.create_node("library/book/title");
n.set_value("Perfect code")
```

should create:

```
<library>
    <book>
        <title>Perfect code</title>
    </book>
</library>
```

The main point here is to create hierarchy in **one line** library/book/title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to create nodes using XPath. It is possible using XQuery, if you want to call that "another kind of path". I don't know specifically if there are XQuery implementations that run against the MSXML DOM, but it seems likely. (Though probably not from Microsoft.)

Comment: MSXML  supports only: XML 1.0, DOM, SAX, an XSLT 1.0 processor, XML schema support including XSD and XDR

Comment: Yes, as I said, you would be looking for some non-Microsoft implementation.